# What benefits do 'perfectly forged' items give in Lego: The Hobbit?

Tags: lego-the-hobbit

When forging mithril items, you can forge a "perfect" version of the item. I know there's an achievement you can get for forging all of the mithril items perfectly, but is there any other benefit to forging the perfect version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The IGN Wiki](http://au.ign.com/wikis/lego-the-hobbit) gives a detailed list of [the mithril treasure items](http://au.ign.com/wikis/lego-the-hobbit/Mithril_Treasure_Items).

While it lists that perfectly forging each item nets the "Unequaled Skill of the Dwarves" achievement, and alters the colour of the item, there is no additional benefits.